# Value in For Loop Only Returning Last Value from YAML

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

So I'm creating an app in Python/Kivy where users can select a checkbox to choose which functions will run. I need each checkbox to append/remove the corresponding value to a list, in which each function will check if its mandated value is present or not in the list to determine if it will run. Most of this, I have already completed via Python/YAML.

The problem is, since the second function doesn't know it's being looped, every checkbox adds or removes 'Reboot' as its value to the list variable when clicked, as opposed to its corresponding label. Which I assume is because it's the final value in the YAML list, and in the second function it doesn't know that it's being iterated through in the first function. In essence, whatever the label reads, I need it to append that value to the list. Aside from that, all of the checkboxes and labels do build properly. My code below:

## **Python**:

```
with open('yaml_config.yaml') as file:
    yaml_config = yaml.safe_load(file)

class FeatureLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selected_items = []

    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()

    def phase1(self):
        self.root.ids.phase_1.clear_widgets()
        for feature in yaml_config['Phase 1']:
            global checkbox_label
            checkbox_label = yaml_config['Phase 1'][feature]
            checkbox = CheckBox(active=False)
            label = FeatureLabel(text=yaml_config['Phase 1'][feature])
            checkbox.bind(active=self.on_checkbox_active)
            self.root.ids.phase_1.add_widget(label)
            self.root.ids.phase_1.add_widget(checkbox)
        return checkbox_label

    def on_checkbox_active(self, checkbox, value):
        if value == True:
            self.selected_items.append(checkbox_label)
            print(self.selected_items)
        else:
            self.selected_items.remove(checkbox_label)
            print(self.selected_items)
```

## **YAML:**

```
Phase 1:
  Step_1: 'Local Admin: Create Account'
  Step_2: 'Local Admin: Automatic Login'
  Step_3: 'Configure Security Policies'
  Step_4: 'Stop/Reset Windows Update'
  Step_5: 'Disable PC Sleep Mode'
  Step_6: 'Configure Power Options'
  Step_7: 'Configure Windows Theme'
  Step_8: 'Configure BG Info'
  Step_9: 'Configure RDP'
  Step_10: 'Make PC Hidden'
  Step_11: 'Configure Send To Menu'
  Step_12: 'Change PC Name'
  Step_13: 'Profile Refinements'
  Step_14: 'Run on Reboot'
  Step_15: 'Reboot'
```

Comment: when you say "_the second function_" ....  do you mean `phase1` ?

Comment: @D.L Phase 1 is the first function. On checkbox active is the second one.